# layoutparser gives error "module layoutparser has no attribute ocr"

Tags: python, ocr

I am trying to use the new layoutparser package to do some OCR. However, coming from an R backgroud I have a hard time getting it up and running.

I installed it via (worked fine):

```
pip install layoutparser
pip install "layoutparser[ocr]"
```

Now, when I run the following I get an error:

```
import layoutparser as lp

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2

ocr_agent = lp.ocr.TesseractAgent()
```

```
AttributeError: module layoutparser has no attribute ocr
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ocr_agent = lp.TesseractAgent()
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why your code would solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (at least no python error):

```
import layoutparser.ocr as ocr
ocr_agent = ocr.TesseractAgent()
```

But need an explaination why the following does not work:

```
import layoutparser as lp
ocr_agent = lp.ocr.TesseractAgent()
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states 'If you would like to use the Detectron2 models for layout detection, you might need to run the following command:'

```
pip install layoutparser torchvision && pip install "detectron2@git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git@v0.5#egg=detectron2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to import pytesseract after layoutparser, torchvision and detectron2 for the same error

```
pip install pytesseract
```